Android - How to display shortcus in widget panel?
I would like to add shortcuts(1x1 size) and display them in Widget panel like Google Maps.

I have tried static shortcut, dynamic shortcut, pinned shortcut
Android developers create shortcuts, none of them show on the widget panel.
I also tried How can you create Shortcuts from an Android Widget?, still not working.
Here is my dev environment:
Android Studio: Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1
Virtual device: Pixel 9 API 35
I hope someone can offer some advice.
Thanks.

Perhaps they are app widgets whose UIs just look like shortcuts.

When shortcuts are placed on the desktop, there will be an app icon at the bottom right corner. So I’m sure they are shortcuts.

I answer my own question.
The answer is this Create Pinned Shortcut
Just follow the tutorial and you will make it.
